# Laravel dropdown list without empty values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating dropdown list from all possible cities in database, all cities are distincted.

`$city = DB::table('contacts')->distinct('city')->lists('id', 'city');`

^ Extracts all possible cities, however it also extract empty string `['' => '95]`.

How I can forbid retrieving empty city ?

I tried using `$city = DB::table('contacts')->whereNotNull('city')->distinct('city')->lists('id', 'city');` But didn't helped. My code looks like this now.

```
    $city = DB::table('contacts')->distinct('city')->lists('id', 'city');
    unset($city['']);
    array_unshift($city, 'Select city');
```

How can I improve it ?

Comment: Can't you just fix your database to remove the corrupted row?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek it's not corrupted, city values are not required

Comment: Did you try `->where('city', '<>', '')`? From the looks of it, whereNotNull is not working because the value is '' (empty string) and that is, indeed, not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the `whereNotNull()` because in addition to allowing empty strings, you allow null values?

That being said, you could always modify your code to use the specific `where()` clause. This can take an `array` as input and you can specify both the empty string and `NULL`.

```
$city = DB::table('contacts')->distinct('city')->lists('id', 'city')->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('contacts.city', '!=', '')
        ->orWhere('contacts.city', '!=', null);
})
```

There's a very good SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342028/using-multiple-where-clauses-with-laravel-query-builder) about multiple where clause queries.